# iphone UITableView Custom Cell selected image

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell which fills the cell with a background PNG and a label.

When the user selected the cell, I wish to have the back ground change for an instant to visually give them indication that the row was selected. Similar to the default behavior when a custom cell is not used.

How is that done?

Comment: I found I can just set this: 
       image.HighlightedImage = the image to use.

Comment: UITableViewCell doesn't have a HighlightedImage property, and neither does its superclass, UIView. UITableViewCell has a highlighted property, but that's a read-only boolean that tells you whether or not it's currently highlighted. Are you saying that you have a UIImage inside your UITableViewCell that provides the background? If so then you're complicating the table cell more than you need to, since there are already properties built into UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this tutorial:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: And why the hell subclassing UITableViewCell is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

Posting as answer so this is correct (originally from BahaiResearch.com):

In this scenario the correct answer is to use the following, when setting the image originally:

```
image.HighlightedImage = [UIImage ..];
```

Otherwise you are loading images when the highlight event occurs and in theory there's a slight delay, etc.

Answer (score 0):

let me clear first do you wish to change the backgroundimage.png??

if yes and you are using UIImageView for that then you can write following code in rowDidSelected event..

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [Cell viewWithTag:1]; //Tag is given in Interface Builder for the ImageView
myImageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] imageNamed:@"newimage.png"];
```